# Python two recursion calls - shared instance of argument

Tags: python, recursion, tree-traversal

I am trying to go through all the possible paths of a 2D matrix (conditions being that I can only go down or right).
Here is what I am trying:

```
rows = 3
columns = 3
# Class definition for node of the tree
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.location = None
#  Starting the tree
tree = Node()
tree.location = [0,0]
def generateRestOfThePath(node):
    print 'Receiving node'
    print node.location
    if (node.location[0] >= rows) or (node.location[1] >= columns):
        print 'Out of playground', node.location
    elif node.location == [rows-1, columns -1]:
        print 'End of a path'
    elif  node.location[0] == rows-1:
        node.location[1] += 1
        print 'Reached bottom can only go right', node.location
        generateRestOfThePath(node)
    elif node.location[1] == columns -1:
        node.location[0] += 1
        print 'Reached right can only go down', node.location
        generateRestOfThePath(node)
    else:
        print 'Neither reached down nor right'  
        node.location[0] += 1
        print 'Going down', node.location
        generateRestOfThePath(node)
        print 'Finished with down', node.location
        node.location[1] +=1
        print 'Going Right', node.location  
        generateRestOfThePath(node)    
generateRestOfThePath(tree)
```

The output that I am getting is this :

```
Receiving node
[0, 0]
Neither reached down nor right
Going down [1, 0]
Receiving node
[1, 0]
Neither reached down nor right
Going down [2, 0]
Receiving node
[2, 0]
Reached bottom can only go right [2, 1]
Receiving node
[2, 1]
Reached bottom can only go right [2, 2]
Receiving node
[2, 2]
End of a path
Finished with down [2, 2]
Going Right [2, 3]
Receiving node
[2, 3]
Out of playground [2, 3]
Finished with down [2, 3]
Going Right [2, 4]
Receiving node
[2, 4]
Out of playground [2, 4]
```

The problem that I have is this :

```
Finished with down [2, 2]
```

Shouldn't this be `[1, 0]` ?

I am thinking this :

```
0,0
 | \ else case
 | 1,0 First recursion call
 | | \else case
 | | 2,0 First recursion call
 | | | only go right case
 | | 2,1 First and only recursive call
 | | | only go right case
 | | 2,2 First and only recursive call
 | | | End of path, No Recursion here
 | | / Since there is no recursion, the second recursion should be called (this is what I am thinking)
 | 1,0 Second recursion call
 | .........
 | .........
 |/
```

But this is not happening. Someone please point me out in the right direction.

Update:

I think that unlike C or C++ python is not keeping the value 1,0 in memory and actually using only one memory location for all instances of node. Which I am thinking are different instances but according to python are all same instances. So I think the real question here is. How to have different instances of node instead of having one shared one?

Comment: You're only generating one node, and modifying that one node.  This would work exactly the same way in C or C++.  The statement `tree = Node()` isn't in a loop or a recursive function.  Why do you think it should be executed more than once?

Comment: @saulspatz Thanks for pointing that out. Can you point me with an example of how I can achieve that ? I will be thankful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this point, you're only creating one node in the whole program, as I said in my comment.   If you want to create a new node for every cell in the matrix that you pass through, you should do it in the call to `generateRestOfThePath()`.  For each possible value of the next node, generate that node, and then call `generateRestOfThePath` with that next node.  If you want to print the starting value when the full path tracing completes, you won't be able to do it in the recursive function.  (That would print the statement each time you finished tracing the possible continuations from each intermediate node.)

Allow me to give you a bit of advice.  You don't need a `Node` class.  You can just use a tuple or a list.  Try to use the built-in structures in python as much as possible.  It will make your life easier.

I don't want to write the code for you, as that won't help you learn.  Try it and give me a shout if you run in more difficulty.  Good luck.

Comment: @saujspatz As I did in the answer that I posted. I am extracting the values from the argument of the function, and whenever I am calling the function I am creating a new tuple. Is this similar to what you are suggesting. Because it looks to me that you are suggesting me to generate a new variable every time I am calling the function and you are suggesting me to use python's inbuilt data structures. Am I correct ?

Comment: You're creating a new list (not a new tuple.)  A tuple looks like `(1,2)`; a list looks like `[1,2]`.  You are modifying a single single instance of Node, however.  My suggestion about using the built-in values is a suggestion for the future, not advice about how to fix this particular script.  Sorry for the confusion.  Have I cleared it up?

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. Thanks for pointing it out. Yes you have cleared the confusion. Thank You very much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your problem is that when you think you are going right, you are actualy going right and down, because the rule

```
node.location[0] += 1
```

is also executed in this case, along with

```
node.location[1] += 1
```

EDIT: sorry, read to quickly, misunderstood your question :)

The line `print "finished with with down ..."` is only executed after your recursive function call completes. This function call only completes after *all* paths from the specific node have completed. Thus, when your script prints out the line `finished with down [1,0]` it has already finished with all nodes accesible from [1,0]. Since you can not travel from [2,2] to the right or bottom, this node will always complete first and thus print out the line `finished with [2,2]` first.

Comment: not to sound rude, but the node that is on the line Finished with down [2, 2] shouldn't be 2, 2 but 1, 0 according to me.  And that's why your suggestion doesn't seems right. However I made the changes and ran the program. It is getting different output, but not what I am expecting. It is sending 1, 3 for the node which is of course out of the matrix.

Comment: But it isn't calling the function with 1,0 as I am expecting it to ? Can you illustrate all the function calls that you are expecting ? Something like the way that I have displayed in the original post ?

Answer (score 0):

Okay since the problem was of only one shared instance and not more than one instance, I have taken a shot and duct-taped the situation. I don't think it is an ideal solution. And I would really really want someone to scold me and put me on the correct path here.

Here is what I did:

```
"The key point here will be that we won't be storing any variables, we will only be passing values"

rows = 3
columns = 3

def generateRestOfThePath(node):
    rowNumber, columnNumber = node
    print 'Receiving node', rowNumber, columnNumber
    if (rowNumber >= rows) or (columnNumber >= columns):
        print 'Out of playground', rowNumber, columnNumber
    elif [rowNumber, columnNumber] == [rows-1, columns -1]:
        print 'End of a path'
    elif rowNumber == rows-1:
        columnNumber += 1
        print 'Reached bottom can only go right', rowNumber, columnNumber
        generateRestOfThePath([rowNumber, columnNumber])
    elif columnNumber == columns -1:
        rowNumber += 1
        print 'Reached right can only go down', rowNumber, columnNumber
        generateRestOfThePath([rowNumber, columnNumber])
    else:
        print 'Neither reached down nor right'  
        rowNumber += 1
        print 'Going down', rowNumber, columnNumber
        generateRestOfThePath([rowNumber, columnNumber])
        print 'Finished with down', rowNumber, columnNumber
        rowNumber -= 1
        columnNumber +=1
        print 'Going Right', rowNumber, columnNumber    
        generateRestOfThePath([rowNumber, columnNumber])
        print 'Finished with right'

generateRestOfThePath([0, 0])
```